# ON predicate of Postgres LATERAL JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, lateral-join

How does `ON` predicate of Postgres `LATERAL JOIN` work?

Let me clarify question a bit. I've read the official documentation and a bunch of articles  about this kind of `JOIN`.

As far as I understood it is a foreach loop with a correlated subquery inside

- it iterates over all records of a table `A`, allowing to reference columns of a "current" row in a correlated subquery `B` and join a result set of the `B` to that "current" row of `A` - if the `B` query returns 1 row there is only one pair, and if the B query return N rows there are N pairs with duplicated "current" row of the A. The same behavior like in usual JOINs.

But why is there a need in `ON` predicate?
For me, in usual JOINs we use `ON` because we have a cartesian product of 2 tables to be filtered out, and it is not the case of `LATERAL JOIN`, which produces resulting pairs directly.
In other words, in my developer experience I've only seen `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and `LEFT JOIN LATERAL () ON TRUE` (the latter looks quite clumsy, though) but one day a colleague showed me

```sql
SELECT
r.acceptance_status, count(*) as count
FROM route r
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT rts.route_id, array_agg(rts.shipment_id) shipment_ids
    FROM route_to_shipment rts
    where rts.route_id = r.route_id
    GROUP BY rts.route_id
) rts using (route_id)
```

and this exploded my mind. Why `using (route_id)`? We already have `where rts.route_id = r.route_id` inside the subquery!

Maybe I understand the mechanics of `LATERAL` joins wrong?

Comment: The given query is just a part of legacy backend we strive to optimize. I agree that it senseless from functional point of view and will be rewritten. But the very fact of presence of non-trivial ON clause near the LATERAL join in real commercial code impressed me to the degree that I decided to post a question. Thanks to @Zegarek I know now it's just a matter of taming the Postgres planning/optimizer.

Comment: `ON` and `USING` allow you to add an extra predicate for the related rows to match. I prefer to keep all predicates centralized in the inner join, and I leave the external one as `ON TRUE` for simplicity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How does ON predicate of Postgres LATERAL JOIN work?

Just the same as in a regular, non-`LATERAL` `JOIN`. It's tied to it independently from what's happening in the subquery.

> But why is there a need in ON predicate?

The fact that the subquery includes what *could* effectively be used the same way a join condition is, doesn't change the syntactic requirements of the `JOIN` outside.

> Why using (route_id)? We already have where rts.route_id = r.route_id inside the subquery!

Whether you apply the condition inside the subquery in the `where`, outside in the `join`, or even further in the outer `where`, or in any combination of the three spots, it changes nothing about the result. One difference that's helpful in this case is that going for `join` allows PostgreSQL to better reason about the query and optimise it: changing `using (route_id)` to `on true` removes that benefit.

It doesn't look like this should matter and ideally, it should not. Unfortunately, the declarative meaning of any query still has to be somehow understood by the [Planner/Optimizer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html). An explicit `join` condition clearly communicates dependency and lets it inspect the relation between the joined tables to apply adequate optimisation techniques. A `lateral join (...)subquery on true` only means that the subquery is meant to be evaluated for each row and `on true` obfuscates *how* it depends on that row - that's left untouched as internal logic of the lateral subquery, and `lateral` merely [*allows*](https://dbfiddle.uk/iP-6hWgG) it to use the external reference, without communicating much more than that to the planner, so it's [left unoptimised](https://dbfiddle.uk/7X2269t4).

Ideally, the planner should peek inside and see the `where`, but it doesn't (at least as of PostgreSQL 16.1). It [doesn't](https://dbfiddle.uk/OvVFwkZX) do that either if you move the `where` out to the outer query, [old-implicit-join-style](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html), although that does help it speed things up in other ways.

---

When you [run your friend's query](https://dbfiddle.uk/yyKKko84), it just makes it more obvious there's nothing useful in the `join` being `lateral`, and further, that there's actually no `join` required. You're not requesting anything from the subquery, so it's only providing matches for `route`, which could be useful to count combinations of matched rows but because you also aggregate there, it can at most provide a single match. In the end, it turns out it contributes *nothing* to the query, which effectively can be shortened first to this:

```sql
SELECT
r.acceptance_status, count(*) as count
FROM route r
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT distinct rts.route_id
    FROM route_to_shipment rts
) rts using (route_id)
group by 1
```

But since `route_to_shipment.route_id` that doesn't match `route.route_id` is ignored thanks to the `left join` and `left join` will fetch unmatched `route.route_id` regardless of their presence in the subquery, it can be completely removed:

```sql
SELECT r.acceptance_status, count(*)
FROM route r group by 1;
```

You'll [get the exact same plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) for all three forms of the query, unsurprisingly short and quick in all cases:

```
QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=41.60..42.10 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=0.590..0.591 rows=5 loops=1)
  Output: r.acceptance_status, (count(*))
  Sort Key: r.acceptance_status, (count(*))
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=31.95..33.95 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=0.583..0.585 rows=5 loops=1)
        Output: r.acceptance_status, count(*)
        Group Key: r.acceptance_status
        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
        ->  Seq Scan on public.route r  (cost=0.00..24.97 rows=1397 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.158 rows=2000 loops=1)
              Output: r.route_id, r.acceptance_status
Planning Time: 0.056 ms
Execution Time: 0.608 ms
```

If you instead `left lateral join...on true`, you're pretending you want the subquery to be evaluated for every row, no matter what, and you obfuscate the dependency, so the planner does literally that:

```
QUERY PLAN
Incremental Sort  (cost=475713.66..475735.06 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=3076.386..3076.388 rows=5 loops=1)
  Output: r.acceptance_status, (count(*))
  Sort Key: r.acceptance_status, (count(*))
  Presorted Key: r.acceptance_status
  Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 25kB  Peak Memory: 25kB
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=475713.59..475726.06 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=3076.153..3076.348 rows=5 loops=1)
        Output: r.acceptance_status, count(*)
        Group Key: r.acceptance_status
        ->  Sort  (cost=475713.59..475717.08 rows=1397 width=32) (actual time=3076.035..3076.135 rows=2000 loops=1)
              Output: r.acceptance_status
              Sort Key: r.acceptance_status
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 86kB
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..475640.60 rows=1397 width=32) (actual time=34.858..3074.645 rows=2000 loops=1)
                    Output: r.acceptance_status
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.route r  (cost=0.00..24.97 rows=1397 width=36) (actual time=0.013..0.387 rows=2000 loops=1)
                          Output: r.route_id, r.acceptance_status
                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..340.44 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=1.536..1.536 rows=1 loops=2000)
                          Output: rts.route_id, NULL::integer[]
                          ->  Seq Scan on public.route_to_shipment rts  (cost=0.00..340.43 rows=101 width=4) (actual time=0.166..1.532 rows=10 loops=2000)
                                Output: rts.shipment_id, rts.route_id
                                Filter: (rts.route_id = r.route_id)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 19990
Planning Time: 0.134 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 11
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 0.896 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.520 ms, Emission 31.319 ms, Total 33.735 ms
Execution Time: 3279.075 ms
```

[Complete demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/K-e_cwwh)

Comment: "make a lot of sense"... can you give an example where on clause makes a lot of sense?

Comment: @SalmanA All I did in this entire answer is pretty much showing why OP's query is the example you request. The version with explicit `using (route_id)` condition enables the entire subquery to get optimized away, while the `on true` blocks that. I don't mean to be rude but right now your comment sounds like you didn't make it past the opening sentence. If the answer is too long, unclear, requires rephrasing, I'll welcome remarks how to improve it.

Comment: Sorry, if the optimizer is generating different plans for the above query then the optimizer is at fault (the query doesn't make sense either... the on clause matches the where clause). May be the optimizer in a future version will do a better job. So again, any case where having an ON clause makes sense when you have a where clause?

Comment: I agree and I point that out in the second paragraph: *Ideally, the planner should peek inside and see the where, but it doesn't*. Maybe this post leaves an impression that I recommend some bizarre lateral join condition syntax to be mandatory, as a general rule - I don't. The idea was to explain why "OP's friend's query" works better and their improvement idea will break that, apart from pointing out what's wrong with both in the first place.

Comment: It's a similar debate to the age-old except vs anti-join, or swapping assymmetric joins - there should be no difference but there just is, at least as of the latest version.

Comment: @Zegrek offtopic, but I've never heard about "swapping asymmetric joins"? What does it mean? Are you about the replacing RIGHT JOIN with LEFT JOIN and vice versa?

Comment: @NikitaGlukhov correct.

Comment: I like how it turned out to be somewhat controversial to open with "this makes sense" before demonstrating that it's through opaque implementation details that it does. Can't say I didn't provoke the downvotes

Comment: @Zegarek I marked your answer as the accepted one, because only you pointed to a non-obvious role of `ON` as an implicit hint to PG planner/optimizer. In everyday battles with long-running queries this kind of knowledge could be very helpful. It may look ugly, but in real commercial code most of us prefer technically justified solutions over the "pretty" ones if the latter ties our hands.

Answer (score -1):

A variant of this question has been answered at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301884/do-postgresql-lateral-joins-require-or-allow-an-on-clause.

In short, the `ON` clause is a syntactic requirement for other than `CROSS JOIN` or `NATURAL JOIN` (the latter of which is an ill-conceived idea that should be expunged from SQL). For `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`, use `ON TRUE` instead of `USING` to avoid unnecessary dependencies on the subquery's select list.